# Detect touches on two separate sprite nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, multi-touch, uitouch, touchesbegan

so what i am trying to do here, is to able to move two of the four sprite nodes, independently from each other. I used an enum to detect what slide was touched then use that information to move the correct node, i know i could of used the name of the node but seemed to work better with what i am trying to do. everything works good so far except i can only move one node at a time. i would like to be able to move... say, leftSlide upwards, while at the same time move rightSlide downwards.

Thank you for any suggestions or comments, any feedback is welcome..

```
var selectedSlides: [SKSpriteNode] = []
var theSlideTouched: SlideTouched = .nothing

enum SlideTouched
{
    case left
    case right
    case bottom
    case top
    case nothing
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{   
    for touch in touches
    {

        if leftSlide.contains((touch.location(in: self)))
        {
            selectedSlides.append(leftSlide)
            theSlideTouched = .left

        }

        if rightSlide.contains((touch.location(in: self)))
        {
            selectedSlides.append(rightSlide)
            theSlideTouched = .right

        }

        if bottomSlide.contains((touch.location(in: self)))
        {
            selectedSlides.append(bottomSlide)
            theSlideTouched = .bottom
        }

        if topSlide.contains((touch.location(in: self)))
        {
            selectedSlides.append(topSlide)
            theSlideTouched = .top
        }
     }
 }

 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        switch theSlideTouched
        {
            case .bottom:
                if selectedSlides.contains(bottomSlide)
                {
                    bottomSlide.color = UIColor.white
                    bottomSlide.position.x = location.x
                }
            case .top:
                if selectedSlides.contains(topSlide)
                {
                    topSlide.color = UIColor.white
                    topSlide.position.x = location.x
                }
            case .left:
                if selectedSlides.contains(leftSlide)
                {
                    leftSlide.color = UIColor.white
                    leftSlide.position.y = location.y
                }
            case .right:
                if selectedSlides.contains(rightSlide)
                {
                    rightSlide.color = UIColor.white
                    rightSlide.position.y = location.y
                }
            case .nothing: break
        }
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
        switch theSlideTouched
        {
            case .bottom: bottomSlide.color = UIColor.clear
            case .top: topSlide.color = UIColor.clear
            case .left: leftSlide.color = UIColor.clear
            case .right: rightSlide.color = UIColor.clear
            case .nothing: break
        }
            theSlideTouched = .nothing
            selectedSlides.removeAll()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the slider objects into their own class. That way you could handle their movement independently and not clutter up your GameScene with these objects. Now when I created this example I placed the objects visually in the GameScene.sks file throughout Scene Editor, so my initialization might be different then yours if you create these in code.

in GameScene...

```
var topSlide: DragObject!
var rightSlide: DragObject!
var bottomSlide: DragObject!
var leftSlide: DragObject!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.view!.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

    if let topSlide = self.childNode(withName: "topSlide") as? DragObject {
        self.topSlide = topSlide
        topSlide.type = .top
    }

    //if you were to create this in code you could do
    //topSlide = DragObject(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    //topSlide.type = .top
    //topSlide.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 500)
    //topSlide.zPosition = 1
    //addChild(topSlide)

    if let rightSlide = self.childNode(withName: "rightSlide") as? DragObject {
        self.rightSlide = rightSlide
        rightSlide.type = .right
    }

    if let bottomSlide = self.childNode(withName: "bottomSlide") as? DragObject {
        self.bottomSlide = bottomSlide
        bottomSlide.type = .bottom
    }

    if let leftSlide = self.childNode(withName: "leftSlide") as? DragObject {
        self.leftSlide = leftSlide
        leftSlide.type = .left
    }
}
```

in DragObject class...

```
class DragObject: SKSpriteNode {

    enum SlideType {
        case left
        case right
        case bottom
        case top
        case nothing
    }

    var type: SlideType = .nothing

    init(color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: color, size: size)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.parent!)

            self.color = .white
            if type == .bottom || type == .top {
                position.x = location.x
            }
            else if type == .left || type == .right {
                position.y = location.y
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.color = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, so a couple questions. why would you leave touchesBegan empty? and can self.view!.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true and isUserInteractionEnabled = true be in viewController?

Comment: I left touchesBegan began empty to show that nothing needed to be in there, and ignore self.view!.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true that was the first idea i had but it's not necessary

Comment: You have a flaw with your drag object class,  if you drag your finger fast enough to get your finger off of the object before the next read, `touchesEnded` will not get called when you release

Comment: @Knight0fDragon good to note for the OP. I wrote it real quick and dirty to get the OP on a path where they could hopefully modify and adapt it to their needs. It wasn't really clear to me what the OP's goals were with their touchesEnded (by making the objects .clear after) so I focused more on the getting 2 objects moving at once. I also have been noticing an influx of new posters that ask a question and never return to comment, or approve answers so right now it is hard to justify spending extra time on answers to just do the work for them.

Comment: Oh I agree 100%,  it is why my activity dropped.  I wasn’t trying to single you out or anything, was just making a note in case you weren’t aware of the behavior that would happen.

Comment: sorry for the late response, thank you so much guys! Your answers completely helped me out and it did in fact point me in the right direction, i fixed the touchesEnded issue, also, i wanted the objects to become clear again so that they wouldn't clutter the screen, since then i have done a few changes here and there, but i trully appreciate the help guys!!

Comment: @stinkyProgram if the answer helped you out please mark it as correct so I can be rewarded for my time and so others will know it as correct and benefit from your questions as well